# Make element collapse with jQuery's animate()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-animate

I'm experimenting with an animation that makes an inline html element collapse on itself (all the elements move to the center). The way I'm approaching it is very clunky and does not work as the width of the element changes.

Here is my attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/JFVxX/1/

HTML

```
<p id="one">1</p> &times; <p id="two">2</p>
```

CSS

```
p {
    display: inline;
    position:relative;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#one').animate({
        left:'+=10'
    });
    $('#two').animate({
        right:'+=10'
    });    
});
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Im looking for a better solution to the one I have: cleaner code and works as the width increases (eg if my numbers are 503 and 62)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JFVxX/4/)

To position them based on their size, ask for their size.  My formula for `w / 2 + 10` is valid for when there is exactly `10px` between the right edge of the first element, and the left edge of the second.

```
<p id="three">12345</p> &times; <p id="four">78910</p>
```

```
$('#three').animate({
    left:'+=' + ( $('#three').width() / 2 + 10 )
});
$('#four').animate({
    right:'+=' + ( $('#four').width() / 2 + 10 )
});
```

---

It goes from this,

[image: uncollapsed text]

to this,

[image: collapsed text]